# Mojibake in emails sent with PHP's mail()

Tags: php, utf-8, mojibake

I currently work for a Japanese client who has an issue receiving the email sent through his contact form built with PHP.

Upon investigation, it seems the mail server's anti-spam fires every time due to a problem that has become my pet peeve the last few months: mojibake.

```
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=9.6 required=7.0 tests=FROM_ILLEGAL_CHARS,
HTML_MESSAGE,HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG,MIME_HTML_ONLY,MISSING_MIMEOLE,RDNS_NONE,
SUBJECT_NEEDS_ENCODING,SUBJ_ILLEGAL_CHARS autolearn=no version=3.2.5
X-Spam-Report: 
    *  4.0 FROM_ILLEGAL_CHARS From: has too many raw illegal characters
    *  1.5 SUBJ_ILLEGAL_CHARS Subject: has too many raw illegal characters
    *  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
    *  1.7 MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
    *  1.3 SUBJECT_NEEDS_ENCODING SUBJECT_NEEDS_ENCODING
    *  1.1 HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG HTML-only message, but there is no HTML tag
    *  0.0 MISSING_MIMEOLE Message has X-MSMail-Priority, but no X-MimeOLE
    *  0.1 RDNS_NONE Delivered to trusted network by a host with no rDNS
```

This even though :

- the form's encoding is set to utf-8
- the script encoding is set to utf-8
- the mail header is set to utf-8 charset and to Base64 for Content-Transfer-Encoding

I also tried to use neitanod 's [toUTF8 library](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8) but it didn't change anything, I still receive what looks like UTF-8 force-encoded to Latin1

```
X-Antivirus: avast (VPS 18071604)
X-Antivirus-Status: Clean
Return-Path: <ap-50728@example.com>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.2.5 (2008-06-10) on
vts18.digitalink.ne.jp
X-Spam-Level: ******
X-Spam-Status: No, score=6.2 required=7.0 tests=AWL,HTML_MESSAGE,
    HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG,MIME_HTML_ONLY,MISSING_SUBJECT,RDNS_NONE,
    SUBJ_ILLEGAL_CHARS autolearn=no version=3.2.5
X-Original-To: xxx@example.com
Delivered-To: xxx@example.com
Received: from vts18.digitalink.ne.jp (unknown [127.0.0.1])
    by vts18.digitalink.ne.jp (Postfix) with ESMTP id C38AD11069044
    for <xxx@example.com>; Tue, 17 Jul 2018 07:23:43 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from www.cosmetic-aida.jp (unknown [182.93.127.172])
    by vts18.digitalink.ne.jp (Postfix) with ESMTP
    for <xxx@example.com>; Tue, 17 Jul 2018 07:23:43 +0000 (UTC)
X-Alpha-Mail-Premier: web2008
Received: by example.com (Postfix, from userid 48)
    id 8072F95D0EF1; Tue, 17 Jul 2018 16:23:46 +0900 (JST)
To: xxx@example.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?æå­åãã¡ã¼ã«?=
From: webmaster@example.com
Reply-To: webmaster@example.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: PHP/5.3.3
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Message-Id: <20180717072346.8072F95D0EF1@www.cosmetic-aida.jp>
Date: Tue, 17 Jul 2018 16:23:46 +0900 (JST)

ãä¸äººæ®ããã§ããææã¾ã§å­¤ç«ããçããã«ã¯ãã©ããªãã¨ãå¿ããããããã®ã§ãããããéºåæ´çå°éä¼ç¤¾ãç«ã¡ä¸ãããå­¤ç«æ­»ããé¿ããããã®åçºã«ãåãçµãåç°å¤ªä¸ããã«èãã¾ããã
```

As for the code I use to produce this, here it is

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding','UTF-8')

$msg = "　一人暮らしでも、最期まで孤立せず生きるには、どんなことを心がけたらよいのでしょうか。遺品整理専門会社を立ち上げ、「孤立死」を避けるための啓発にも取り組む吉田太一さんに聞きました。\r\n
";
$myHeaders = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";
$myHeaders .= 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";
$myHeaders .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'. "\r\n";
$myHeaders .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(). "\r\n";
$myHeaders .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'. "\r\n";

$mailOK = (mail(
    "xxx@example.com", 
    "=?UTF-8?B?"."文字化けメール"."?=", 
    $msg, 
    $myHeaders
    )) ? "Mail sent" : "Error sending mail";

echo $mailOK;
```

Am I chasing the wrong issue?
For those of you used to sending non-latin encoded characters, how do you deal with that?

[EDIT] Added a complete raw email and the script used to produce it

Comment: What code are you using to send the mail, what does the actual raw email look like (headers and body)?

Comment: Edited the message with the requested information.

Comment: You need to MIME-encode all those header fields containing non-ASCII characters, as the spam report clearly indicates.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves 60% of the problem.
I'll dive into why the main content is garbled (which is the main issue of my client)